# How to disable (or hide) DotNetNuke Layout mode for a user role?

Tags: dotnetnuke

this should be a simple task, however googling didn't help.

When I am logged in as administrator in dnn, there is control ribbon at the top with Mode: radio buttons in top left corner. These are View, Edit and Layout.

Is it possible to make Layout selection impossible? Hide it or disable for administrators? We had a couple problems already whey people had this option chosen and they drag and drop modules inadvertently, messing with layout.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this you would likely need to modify the Control Panel code, or create your own control panel, I can't think of any way to do this otherwise.